# Why is my Spring Boot 3 application showing empty measurements when running inside Kubernetes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

When running my application locally I get the usual group names at `/actuator/metrics`. If I query for a group, e.g. `/actuator/metrics/jvm.classes.loaded`, I get a decent result:

```
{
  "name": "jvm.classes.loaded",
  "description": "The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine",
  "baseUnit": "classes",
  "measurements": [
    {
      "statistic": "VALUE",
      "value": 12868.0
    }
  ],
  "availableTags": [
    
  ]
}
```

The very same application with identical configuration, but running inside a k8s cluster has an empty measurement without any values:

```
{
  "name": "jvm.classes.loaded",
  "description": "The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine",
  "baseUnit": "classes",
  "measurements": [
    
  ],
  "availableTags": [
    
  ]
}
```

This is the same for all metric groups (names shown at `/actuator/metrics` are the same on local and k8s version).

I also do have a `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint. This one is working fine both locally and inside k8s, so the values are actually recorded.

Local

```
# HELP jvm_classes_loaded_classes The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine
# TYPE jvm_classes_loaded_classes gauge
jvm_classes_loaded_classes 12868.0
```

Kubernetes

```
# HELP jvm_classes_loaded_classes The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine
# TYPE jvm_classes_loaded_classes gauge
jvm_classes_loaded_classes 17614.0
```

So why is Spring not showing any measurements? Is this a bug or a "special Spring kubernetes magic"? Is there any configuration to force Spring to show the metrics?